# How to add the hover effect from the brower with css

Tags: css, hover

I am trying to add the hover effect to my web application.

I used:

```
  .families-container{
margin-bottom: 1em;
padding-bottom: 2em;
height: 22%;
border: solid black 2px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color: #D8D8D8;
padding-left: 3em;
padding-top: 1em;
display: table;
width: 97%;
```

}

I am trying to add the outline hover effect to the container. When you select a box in chrome or firefox, I want that blue outline, but the outline I added does not wrap around the original container.

```
.hover-effect:hover {
 box-shadow: 3px 4px 14px black;
 outline: solid rgb(19,108,214,0.8) 3px;
 outline-offset: -5px;
   }
```

The outline shows a blue square box and I am looking for a rounded box.
Is there some webkit I could be using to add the hover outline so that it matches the curved edges. Can you change the radius of an outline? What is the code to create the hover effect for any browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an absolutely-positioned pseudo element for this. Hide the pseudo element normally, and display it on hover.

```css
.families-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  height: 22%;
  border: solid black 2px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  display: table;
  width: 97%;
  position: relative;
}

.families-container::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -4px;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid rgb(19,108,214,0.8);
  box-shadow: 3px 4px 14px black;
  border-radius: 17px;
  display: none;
}

.families-container:hover::after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="families-container"></div>
```